# .Net Core 2 deployment to IIS 2012 R2 - 500 Internal Service Error - no logs

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .Net Core2 App that I have successfully deployed to over a dozen servers. No problem. I pretty much know what I am doing.

Now I have a machine that has me stuffed. It gives a 500 error when run through IIS, but runs perfectly from the command prompt locally e.g. http://localhost:5000/

I have done all the usual things;
1. Installed .Net 4.7 (mine is based on .Net platform due to legacy libs)
2. Installed the .Net Core hosting on IIS (v2.05)
3. Enabled the logs in the web config
4. Created the logs folder and checked that it has the IIS APPPOOL permissions
5. Run it from the command prompt (it works perfectly and processes requests)

It does not create a log either for the IIS logs or my application (the latter is no surprise, because it doesn't look like the app is even started). I have had a variety of issues before, but have always been able to get the lost to figure it out - not this time. Nothing in the windows logs either.

I tried running my app from the prompt, and got a Visual C++ missing error - this is weird because MSVC++ is a prerequisite that should have been installed with the service hosting. Never mind - I installed both 86 and 64 bit versions. Then I uninstalled and reinstalled the windows server hosting for .Net Core.

My application now runs from the command prompt and just says listening on localhost:5000. Cool.

But it still wont run in IIS. An it still wont produce a log.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out that the standard web.config that comes with the .Net core project template contains this innocuous looking line

```
<modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```

99% of the time this goes through to the keeper because webdav is enabled by default. But if it isn't... BOOM. App doesnt even start in IIS

Just take it out of the config